# Using Await in a Catch Block

Tags: c#, async-await

In my application a user attempts to login. Sometimes the website will fail a login - even if credentials are correct - and ask the user to enter a captcha code. Meaning they have to attempt to login twice.

My application has 2 custom exceptions that are thrown on either login failure, or when the website is asking a user to enter a captcha. Here they are:

```
class LoginFailedException : Exception
{
    public LoginFailedException() { }
    public LoginFailedException(string message) : base(message) { }
}

class LoginFailedCaptchaRequiredException : Exception
{
    public LoginFailedCaptchaRequiredException() { }
    public LoginFailedCaptchaRequiredException(string message) : base(message) { }
}
```

In my application I catch both of these exceptions. When a `LoginFailedCaptchaRequiredException` is thrown I catch it, but I need to present a dialog to the user with the captcha image, asking them to enter the text from the captcha image. Once they've entered the text I then need to call 'await LoginWithCaptcha'.

But the problem is I can not use `await` inside the `catch`. What alternative solutions can I try here?

And here is my login button:

```
private async void btnLogin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        try
        {
            webclient = new WebsiteAPI("username", "password");
            await webclient.Login();
            MessageBox.Show("Logged In");
        }
        catch (LoginFailedException ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Login Failed");
        }
        catch (LoginFailedCaptchaRequiredException ex)
        {
            // 1. Show dialog with Captcha
            // 2. Get captcha text entered by user
            // 3. await LoginWithCaptcha(string captchaText, string captchaKey);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Something Bad Happened");
        }
    }
```

How can I get around this?

Comment: Do it outside the catch?

Comment: I forgot to add. I have been following a lot of the practices taught in a book called Clean Code. The authors states that if possible, when a try/catch block is used in a function nothing should come before, or after, the try/catch block. I'm following the good design practice to keep functions small (still have to refactor yet). Non of the solutions I have found take this into account.

Comment: @JamesJeffery You're not always going to have success applying practices for non-async code to async code.  While `await` does allow it to look a lot more similar, there sill are differences, and it does need to have at least some affect on coding practices.

Answer (score 0):

Have the `catch` block simply indicate that you have some work to do, and then do it after the end of the whole `try/finally`:

```
bool tryToLoginWithCaptcha = false;

try
{
    //...
}
catch (LoginFailedCaptchaRequiredException ex)
{
    // 1. Show dialog with Captcha
    // 2. Get captcha text entered by user
    tryToLoginWithCaptcha = true;
}

if(tryToLoginWithCaptcha)
    await LoginWithCaptcha(captchaText, captchaKey);
```

If you have a more complex decision as to what to do then you can of course have, say, a `List<Task>` to `await` instead of just a boolean.